# JavaScript: change implementation of library function

Tags: javascript

I know that I have never use the following way and I promise don't do it but just a question why it does not work.

I have a library where I have the following class:

```
export default class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }

  myMethod() {
    console.log(5);
  }
}
```

This class uses in this lib and not assume that somebody will try to use it outside the lib.

And in my file where I'm trying to make:

```
const myClass = require('myLib').default;
const _method = myClass.prototype.myMethod;

myClass.prototype.myMethod = function () {
  console.log(123);
  _method();
}
```

And... As you can understand it does not work and class MyClass continue to use his own myMethod.

I want to note (I checked it in chrome debugger) that firstly class MyClass defines in the lib. After that my code with override runs. And only after that constructor of class MyClass runs.
So, technically I cannot find the problem and if run all this code in one file it works. 
But when it's all in the context of a library, no.

So, the main question - why? What happens with class inside JavaScript?

Comment: are you calling the method in the file where you modified it ?

Comment: No, this class (I mean MyClass) uses only in the lib. And the method also calls in the lib.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should give you an idea of a few caveats that you can run into with modifying a class prototype. And if you don't control the prototype, then this is a pain to handle. If you need to do this, [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) are often the best option.

```js
class Foo {
  run() {
    console.log('running foo, this:', this)
  }
}

const foo = new Foo()
console.info('before changing Foo.prototype')
foo.run()

console.info('changing Foo.prototype')
const originalRun = Foo.prototype.run
Foo.prototype.run = function() {
  console.warn('modified foo method running - original should be next. this:', this)
  originalRun() // won't have the correct `this` binding (`.apply` can fix that), but works otherwise
}

foo.run()

// But if you have a class that modifies the prototype methods and makes them instance methods, things are different

class Bar {
  constructor() {
    // create a modified version of `run`. Could be modified in many ways, but binding is most common.
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'run', {
      value: this.run.bind(this),
      ennumerable: false
    })
  }
  run() {
    console.log('running bar, this:', this)
  }
}

const bar = new Bar()
console.info('before changing Bar.prototype')
bar.run()

console.info('changing Bar.prototype')
const originalBarRun = Bar.prototype.run
Bar.prototype.run = function() {
  console.warn('modified bar method running - original should be next. this:', this)
  originalBarRun()
}

// notice how the constructor ran before we changed prototype and made changes before we could, so our changes ae missed
bar.run()

const barAfterChange = new Bar()
console.info('running new bar after change')
// This modifies the prototype bar, but now the changes the constructor makes are on the modified method, and not the original
barAfterChange.run()
```

Comment: As I understand, the final implementation of function depends on the moment when the instance was created. 
I mean that if in both cases we firstly replace function and only after that make `const bar = new Bar()` it will work with our new function, is not it?
But in my case, it did not work. I changed function before calling the constructor. 
The difference with your code was that I tried to change the function from the class which was imported from another lib.

Comment: Like I demonstrated, there can be an issue if the library code is modifying the function in the constructor. In that case, wrapping an instance method isn't easy. Import is unlikely to be the issue here, as modules don't really change the behavior of how objects work. In fact, if you are using something like Webpack, it may even turn the modules into inline code.